# How to properly test logger with unittest?

Tags: python, logging, python-unittest

I have a function that sets up logger for my module:

```py
import logging
...
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def setup_logger(level=logging.INFO):
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        fmt='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    )

    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(level)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    LOGGER.setLevel(level)
    LOGGER.addHandler(handler)
    LOGGER.debug('Logger is set up...')
```

Now I want to test my code that for example my logger is indeed fires that debug message. I try the following:

```py
def test_setup_logger(self):
    with self.assertLogs(LOGGER, level='DEBUG') as cm:
        setup_logger(level=10)
        self.assertListEqual(cm.output, [2021-11-21 20:39:23 DEBUG: Logger is set up...])
```

And then I get this message:

```
AssertionError: Lists differ: ['DEBUG:app.main:Logger is set up...'] != ['2021-11-21 20:39:23 DEBUG: Logger is set up...']
```

Which apparently means that my `LOGGER` formatting was not set up. How do I test this properly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your test will never successful because you set static `datetime`(as `str`).

`cm.output` includes printed messages using format `{LOG_LEVEL}:{LOGGER_NAME}:{MESSAGE}`. Yes, you can check full format using `cm.records` + `handler.formatter`. Something like:

```
class TestExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_setup_logger(self):
        with self.assertLogs(LOGGER) as cm:
            now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            setup_logger(logging.DEBUG)
            # Ran 1 test in 0.002s OK...
            self.assertEqual(
                LOGGER.handlers[1].format(cm.records[0]),
                '{} DEBUG: Logger is set up...'.format(now)
            )
```

But... I don't understand what it is for. It looks like you want to write a test for the `logging` package. Usually you need to check log records(`cm.output`) after important functionality.

Also you can create a test for the logger configuration. And check only required log records in the other tests. Just an example:

```
class TestLoggerSetup(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_setup_logger(self):
        setup_logger(logging.DEBUG)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(LOGGER.handlers[0], logging.StreamHandler))
        self.assertEqual(LOGGER.handlers[0].formatter.datefmt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.assertEqual(LOGGER.level, logging.DEBUG)


 class TestLogMessages(unittest.TestCase):
     def test_my_function(self):
         with self.assertLogs(LOGGER) as cm:
             LOGGER.info(111)
             # or my_function() blablabla... and check only log records:
             self.assertListEqual(cm.output, ['INFO:main:111'])
```